# Handling events in NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, events, fullscreen, nswindow

I'm trying to handle key events of full-screen NSWindow. I've subclassed NSWindow and realized methods keyDown and canBecomeKeyWindow (which is returning YES). But my key events are not handling. Here is how i'm creating window:

```
    mainWindow = [[FullScreenWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:screenRect
                                             styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                               backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                 defer:NO screen:[NSScreen mainScreen]];

    [mainWindow setLevel:windowLevel];

    [mainWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    [mainWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

Where FullScreenWindow is a subclass of NSWindow. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Generally handling key events in an `NSWindow` object is a bad idea, you normally handle these in a control, view or in a subclass of `NSWindowController`. Is there a reason you need to handle key events in the window itself? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i'm trying to quit from full-screened window, by esc key-pressing

Answer (score 0):

The `esc` key already exists fullscreen by default, you don't have to implement It (tested on 10.10.4).